# Bot Framework - Can't get response from Skype

Tags: bots, botframework, skype

I have created a bot application using Microsoft Bot Framework.
It's working locally fine, but when I add it to Skype we could not get the response from Skype.
My endpoint url is:
http://balajiamishra-001-site1.htempurl.com

Comment: Did you upload the bot with the correct credentials? A good way to figure your problem is to add application insights to the bot in order to check for exceptions and errors.

Answer (score 1):

At least two things are incorrect with your endpoint URL and probably you get errors because of that.

1. Endpoint URL should be HTTPS instead of HTTP as HTTP is not allowed.
2. Second, you should always keep in mind adding this to the end of your endpoint url:
   /api/messages
   otherwise you might get mad errors.

So your endpoint URL should look like this:
https://balajiamishra-001-site1.htempurl.com/api/messages

Additional notes:

- Your URL looks odd. If I got it right that it's some temporary url then instead consider using [ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator) for exposing bot your bot. It's easier and also gives you https with valid certificate.
- More details about configuring bot can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-register-bot#register-your-bot).